# Uploaded audio only short noise

Tags: c#, php, windows-phone-8

I am trying to build an uploading-method, which uploads a recorded .wav to my server.
The problem is, that the uploading file is just noise and has always the same size.

Can you tell me why this is & how to to fix it?

```
private void upload()
{
    var isoStore = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    if (isoStore.FileExists("AudioTest.wav"))
    {
        System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream _data =
            isoStore.OpenFile("AudioTest.wav", FileMode.Open);

        byte[] fileContent = new byte[_data.Length];
        int bytesRead = _data.Read(fileContent, 0, 4096);

        string b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileContent, 0, 4096);

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

        wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://myhost.de/t/upload.php?upload"),
            "&contents=" + b64);

        wc.UploadStringCompleted += (a, b) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Upload done");
        };
    }
}
```

and this is the PHP-Side

```
<?php
    echo "Starting upload\n";

    if(isset($_GET["upload"]))
    {
        $contents = $_POST["contents"];
        echo $filename;
        try
        {
            $file = fopen("filename.wav", "w");
            $input = base64_decode($contents);
            fwrite($file, $input);
            fclose($file);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reading and encoding to Base64 and always setting the same size 4096. You might want to try

```
int bytesRead = _data.Read(fileContent, 0, _data.Length - 1);

string b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileContent, 0, _data.Length);
```

Secondly URL Encode your string due to the fact that base64 can have + signs in it.

```
wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://myhost.de/t/upload.php?upload"),
        "&contents=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(b64));
```

and on the PHP side

```
$input = base64_decode(urldecode($contents));
```

Comment: Ok now the uploaded file is bigger, but it's still just noise

Comment: Edited the response as the issue is most likely a URLEncoding issue.

Comment: Also I notice you are using ISO-8859-1 encoding. Try removing that line, or replacing it with UTF8

Comment: Thanks, but the problem still exists

Comment: First, can you please confirm that if you play the .wav file at the source it is captured it works. This is just to ensure it is actually the transfer that is corrupting it and that it isn't corrupted before you are sending it.

Comment: Second if you can try this. If you can convert from base64 back to a byte array and save it, then play the wav file again, in .NET and see if it still works. Next then see if the Base64 you are sending in the URL is exactly the same as what the PHP is receiving. Generally you can compare them side by side to quickly see if there is any major difference.

Comment: I can confirm that the two b64s (client/server) are the same. The file itself is working on the client, too. I think the problem is the conversion to byte-form